# inet PDFc unable to recognize characters

Tags: inet

I was using PDFc to compare two files using ConsoleResultHandle.
Both my files were similar , I had copy pasted them.

This tool Pdfc after comparing was giving
DEBUG - Unsupport CMap format: 6

I checked the differences folder (where it shows the differences) and in the png files it generates , its giving all boxes ..(unsupported characters) as the above debug says.

Did anyone else encounter the same problem.

Comment: Did you already check back with our support? I know we'd like to do everything to help you out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can occur if there are issues parsing the PDF file. The best way to proceed, as gamma mentions in the comment, is to contact our support team at pdfc@inetsoftware.de with the PDFs in question - we usually answer within 24 hours and will see if we can fix the problem.